# jquery google maps not able to set location

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using jquery google maps plugin. This is my code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


    var locations = [];
    locations.push([{
        'position': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 
        'bounds': true
    }, 'Hello World!']);


    $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(ev, map) {
        for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i+=1) {

            var loc = locations[i];

            /*
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', loc[0]).click(function() {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': loc[1]}, this);
            });
            */
        }


        $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'zoom', 10);


        if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
            function success(pos) {
                // Location found, show map with these coordinates
                //drawMap(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));


                $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 
                    'center': new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude)
                });


                //alert(pos.coords.latitude);
                //alert(pos.coords.longitude);

                //$('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': '42.345573,-71.098326' });
            }
            function fail(error) {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': '42.345573,-71.098326' });
            }

            // Find the users current position.  Cache the location for 5 minutes, timeout after 6 seconds
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {maximumAge: 500000, enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 6000});
        } else {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': '42.345573,-71.098326' });
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that, I want to set the location (not marker) to where the user is, but the problem is that the code won't move the location. It keeps it at a default lat/long 0,0. I don't know what is wrong. I put an alert statement in the success function and it does the alert..

Does anyone know whats going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript very often uses asynchronous processes.  That means: you (the scripter) send a request, accompanied by a callback.  Javascript takes what ever time it takes, whenever it's ready, it will call that callback.

In the meantime, it continues with the rest of the script; it doesn't wait.

geolocation is one of those asynchronous services.  You send a request, the rest of the script continues; if and when geolocation finds the location, only then you use that functionality.

That means you always need a default; you always need to write default code for when geolocation fails.

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jquery google maps not able to set location</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
    <script>
    function initialize() {
      // we send a request to get the position of the client.
      // This can take some time, so we don't wait.
      // We create the map and set a default location.
      // If and when geolocation found the client's location, we change the center of the map
      //   else, we don't

      // new map, with default location
      $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 
        center: '42.345573,-71.098326',
        zoom:   10
      });
      if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
        function success(pos) {
          // set the center
          $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'center',  new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
        }
        function fail(error) {
          // maybe you want to do something here
        }
        // start of the request to get the client's position
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {maximumAge: 500000, enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 6000});
      }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    <style>
      #map_canvas {
        height: 500px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```